# kendo grid filter operators missing

Tags: kendo-grid

On the datasource of kendo grid I specified, in model, the type for each field.

In kendo grid for string, number and date I specified all the operators for each type.

However I can see only 'eq' and 'neq' operators (also for string, number and date fields).

Here is how i defined filterable.operators in my kendo grid:

```
    filterable: {       

            operators: {
                //filter menu for "string" type columns
                string: {
                    eq: "Uguale a",
                    neq: "Diverso da",
                    startswith: "Comincia con",
                    contains: "Contiene",
                    endswith: "Termina per"
                },
                //filter menu for "number" type columns
                number: {
                    eq: "Uguale a",
                    neq: "Diverso da",
                    gte: "Maggiore o uguale a",
                    gt: "Maggiore di",
                    lte: "Minore o uguale a",
                    lt: "Minore di"
                },
                //filter menu for "date" type columns
                date: {
                    eq: "Uguale a",
                    neq: "Diverso da",
                    gte: "Successiva o uguale al",
                    gt: "Successiva al",
                    lte: "Precedente o uguale al",
                    lt: "Precedente al"
                }
            }                    
        }
```

==========================================

[image]

Comment: This part of the code seems legit to me.  Can you post the full grid initialization parameter?

Comment: The image doesn't help much... it ain't related to kendo grid initialization. It's only showing the model.

Comment: You're right, I'll update as soon as possible, thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't answer by editing your question.  Write your own answer and accept it to let other SO users you have found a solution to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in grid columns configuration.

For all columns I had a 'values' array.

It is useful for columns that must be filtered by static values (filter by sex, values: ['M', 'F']).

The problem arises when array values is empty.

Solved deleting values property when values array is empty.